# mongodb increment counter on select

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Is there any way to update the documents by incrementing ($incr) their counter field (lets say there is a counter field) by 1 when the documents are returned by a find command ?

or,

there are no ways but to update this manually?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no support for internal triggering or anything similar in MongoDB. 
You'll have to do that manually.

[Here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-124) is the discussion about the triggers feature.

Comment: super fast response. thanks. SO needs at least 12 mins to allow me to accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at using findAndModify? You can find the doc, atomically update it, and then return it in one operation.

Comment: Thanks. This is something new to me. Will check this in detail.